# How can I have two command decorators that go against each other?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a command that deletes a specified number of messages entered in by the user. I want this command to be accessible only to me and those with the administrator role. I had implemented this before with if-statements, and it was working perfectly fine. However, now I'm trying to use command decorators to do the same, and it only lets administrators use the command - not me. Here's the code I'm working with:

```py
@bot.command(description="clears entered amount of messages")
@commands.is_owner() # checks if user is owner
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True) # checks if user is admin
async def delete(ctx, amount : int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount + 1)
```

The `@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)`, I think, is blocking me from using the command, since I'm not an administrator in one of the servers. I've tried switching their orders, with the `is_owner()` check being below the `has_permissions()` check; nonetheless, it still doesn't allow me to use the command. How can I overcome this using decorators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom decorator that will check if you're either the owner of the bot, or you are an admin

```py
def owner_or_admin():
    def predicate(ctx):
        owner = ctx.author.id == bot.owner_id # Comparing the author of the message with the owner of the bot
        perms = ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator # Checking for admin perms
        return owner or perms
    return commands.check(predicate)


@bot.command(description="clears entered amount of messages")
@owner_or_admin()
async def delete(ctx, amount : int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount + 1)
```

EDIT: I just found out about [`commands.check_any`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.check_any) - checks if any of the checks passed will pass, i.e. using logical `OR`.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.check_any(commands.is_owner(), commands.has_permissions(administrator=True))
async def delete(ctx, amount: int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount + 1)
```

Comment: For some reason, even though your logic and code seem perfectly correct to me, the command won't delete the messages. So, I've made some changes to it by initializing the boolean values to `False` and changing their values according to 2 if-statements. I'll upvote your answer and mark it as correct, since it was basically correct in its logic. However, since it's not working for me (and I don't want to edit your answer because it might work for someone else) I'm going to post my own answer to this question.

Comment: Feel free to check out the edit, just found out about `commands.check_any`, a shorter version of what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be the same for me,

```
@bot.command(description="clears entered amount of messages")
@commands.is_owner() # checks if user is owner
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True) # checks if user is admin
async def delete(ctx, amount : int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount + 1)
```

I am able to purge messages.
I suspect you haven't got your discord permissions set up correctly,
try to make sure you have the permission **[manage_messages](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.purge)** enabled

Read the Discord [API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#) for more info

Comment: The bot has `manage_messages` enabled - that's not the problem. What the problem is that in servers where I am not administrator, I cannot run the command. If, however, I am in a server and I have the administrator role, then the command works.

Comment: Well yes, that's what the 3rd decorator does, that's the point of it. Just because you're an admin in 1 random server doesn't mean you should be able to do whatever you want in every other server your bot is in. If you don't want that then remove it & use an `if` that checks specifically for your Discord id (either in the function or in a custom decorator)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ŁukaszKwieciński, I learned that I needed to make a custom decorator that would check for bot ownership and administrator role, and would return `False` if both of them are False, and `True` if one of them is True.

```py
def owner_or_admin():
    def predicate(ctx):
        owner = False
        perms = False
        if ctx.author.id == bot.owner_id:
            owner = True
        if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
            perms = True 
        return owner or perms
    return commands.check(predicate)

@bot.command(description="clears entered amount of messages")
@owner_or_admin()
async def delete(ctx, amount : int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount + 1)
```

Comment: This will still work like `commands.has_permissions` decorator, you're comparing in the first if-statement if `owner` (the boolean initialized two lines before) is equal to the owner ID, that'll always be `False`. You should change it to `ctx.author.idd == bot.owner_id`

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński oops, that was a copying error.