# How do you make a role-specific command and also a permission specific command

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make a command that can only be used by a role named 'DJ' and also the roles that has the 'Manage Channels' permission

I tried adding the two blocks that makes this possible `@commands.has_permissions(manage_guild=True)`
`@commands.has_role('DJ')`

But they seem to not work together as it gives me a Missing Permission error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check it by yourself.

```
async def check_is_role(ctx):
   roles = ctx.author.roles
   role = find(lambda x: x.name == 'DJ', roles)  # using lambda to find role_name
   if role:
       return true    # or do something
   else:
       await ctx.send('you don't have permission')
       return false
```

To make a custom decorator, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66775954/how-can-i-have-two-command-decorators-that-go-against-each-other)

Comment: can i make this a single decorator? and also just find the role named "DJ"

Comment: @felixoofed does this solve your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66775954/how-can-i-have-two-command-decorators-that-go-against-each-other

Comment: I also edited my code to `role.name`, you can check if it work well :)

Comment: thanks the question and answer solved my problem (i wish i could upvote but reputations exist)

Comment: @felixoofed you can accept my answer by clicking the check mark, that's should below the upvote part of my answer